# Rules limiting Spiritual Weapons?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, cleric, minion

[Spiritual Weapon](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/spiritualWeapon.htm) is a level 2 Evocation [force] spell that conjures a floating weapon for one round per level. It does not appear to be a buff, as the weapon seems to be a self-sufficient object, similar to an animal targeted by the Handle Animal skill. If you spend a move action directing it to attack a target, it will continue attacking that target until you spend another move action redirecting it, the target moves outside of the spell's range, or the spell ends.

Is there anything preventing a character from having more than one spiritual weapon active? The way I read the spell, it seems to be an evoker's response to the Summon Monster spells, with specific drawbacks due to it being in a school not suited for creating long-term manifestations. As a result, there doesn't seem to be any reason a motivated character can't have a small fleet of these weapons orbiting them, regardless of how impractical that would be.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question's premise. Are you asking why/if people can't pre-cast spiritual weapons and direct one per round at enemies during combat with spare move actions? I don't see much benefit to having such a fleet, not to mention that it would cost one spell slot per round to maintain, unless you almost never use move actions.

Comment: I am asking if a cleric could cast the spell three times and have three spiritual weapons active at once. I understand that directing them using move actions would be cumbersome, but I'm simply wondering if there's anything preventing the character from doing it in the first place.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did the DM say that you couldn't?

Comment: As to the why, it's mostly because I'm interested in playing as Gilgamesh from Fate. A combination of spiritual weapon, HammerSpheres, Manyjaws, Cloud of Knives, etc. Maybe even throwing in that specialist Psychic Warrior that conjures specific weapons, however I don't think that comes with the dancing property, so maybe not.

Comment: I haven't spoken to them about it yet. I'm more wondering if the character concept is even viable.

Comment: I don't think it answers your Q in description but (per the title Q) I believe a limitation would be the move action to make it attack a target as it says "the weapon".  So if you have 10 that's 10 move actions to direct them all.  If you feel that's an answer to your Q, I am happy to make it.  But it doesn't negate the answer already given which does answer your described Q.  So otherwise, be prepared for that pushback from the judge if you weren't already (it's what I'd rule).  If it's just visual, the 1 round/level will be more the limitation (or thing to figure out) I imagine :)

Comment: Well, if it is just a matter of flavour you could reskin the spirit guardians spell to be a collection of spirit weapons. At least that would be what I'd do in 5e, you've linked the 3.5e spiritual weapon spell and I don't know whether spirit guardians is a thing in 3.5e but you could perhaps make one with your DM if not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### You can have multiple *spiritual weapons* at the same time

As far as I can see, there is nothing in the spell description that would prohibit you from casting the spell several times. The [stacking rules](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/castingSpells.htm#stackingEffects) for combining magical effects also do not apply to it, as it is not providing a bonus to something.

You may need opponents, as the spell says

> A weapon made of pure force springs into existence **and attacks opponents at a distance**, as you direct it

but this might be imaginary opponents, and you can target any spot if you want to move it. As it continues to attack the same opponent without you needing to do anything for that, you could have a small fleet of them all pummeling someone, it seems.

Comment: Description is not proscription. If the spell required a target to attack, it would indicate that explicitly.

Comment: There is just no rules in the spell how to move it without attacking anyone, as far as I can see. But you have _much_ deeper experience with this edition, I’ll adapt the answer.

Comment: Keeping in mind that, so far as I'm aware, *opponent* isn't a game term, I sometimes get very at my multitude of invisible enemies. `:-)`

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin “That spot on the ground” is a legal, valid (and sometimes even [meaningful](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/specialAttacks.htm#throwSplashWeapon)) target in this edition.

Answer (score 3):

### You can have multiple Spiritual Weapons going. It's not that advantageous.

When you first get it, spiritual weapon is going to eat one action to last for three rounds and hit about half the time, averaging 5.5 damage when it hits. That's equivalent to just under three damage/round, steady-state. One second-level spell for about 8 damage, coming in slow.

That duration will gradually get longer, but also not matter: fights (usually) end fast in 3.5, so any duration longer than about 5 rounds is an illusion.

Damage will grow too, but not in a way that matters: At sixth level, your damage per hit goes up by 1, so your damage per round goes up by 0.5. Same at ninth. At eighth level, you get an iterative attack that doesn't hit anyway. It probably boosts your expected damage output by ~10%. All in all, by the time you hit 10th, you likely have more like 4.5 damage per round, per weapon (AC is divergent enough that you aren't going to get anything more precise than "hits about half the time").

So what about having a bunch of them? Well, they take time to cast, you can only move one per round to a new target (because it's a move action), and they eat your spell slots to put them up. A fourth-level cleric with the war domain can spend three rounds putting up three spiritual weapons. If they get to stay on the same target, he will have expected cumulative damage per round:
1: 2.75
2: 8.25
3: 16.5
4: 24.75
5: 31.25
6: 34

Three spells, three standard actions, and this tactic only does 34 (expected) damage total, after 6 rounds (that's a little optimistic - more likely, your target dies before the cleric acts in round three when the rogue shanks him).

It still has uses like bypassing damage reduction and hitting incorporeal things early on, but spiritual weapon overall is more fun than good.